# If statement changing image to greyscale

Tags: javascript

currently i have an image converted to greyscale, it does this on the click of a button. I need to be able to remove this function either by using the same button or another button. I thought this would be possible by using an if statement although im not sure how to do this.

```
<html>
<body>
<script>

    function greyscale(){
    //get canvas    
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    //get the context property
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    //get image
    var image = document.getElementById("imgSrc");
    //draw image to canvas
    ctx.drawImage(image,0,0);
    //get the image data
    var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,130,130);
    //get the pixel data
    var px = imageData.data;
    //get entire length of pixel data
    var length = px.length;

    //loop and manipulate the pixels
    for(var i=0;i<length;i+=4){
        var redPx = px[i];
        var greenPx = px[i+1];
        var bluePx = px[i+2];
        var alphaPx = px[i+3];    

        //create greyscale sub pixel
        var greyscale = redPx*.3 + greenPx * .59 + bluePx * .11;

        //store each subpixel as that greyscale subpixel
        px[i] = greyscale;
        px[i+1] = greyscale;
        px[i+2] = greyscale;

        }

    //put the manipulated image data back into the canvas
    ctx.putImageData(imageData,0,0);

    }
</script><img src="flower.jpg" id="imgSrc"/>
<canvas id="canvas" width="130" height="130"></canvas>

<br>

</script>

<input id="btngreyscale" type="button" value="Greyscale" onclick="greyscale();" />
<input id="btngreyscaleoff" type="button" value="Greyscale Off" onclick="loadImage();" />

<br>
<input type="radio" name="zing" id="on" checked/>on
<input type="radio" name="zing" id="off"/>off

<script type="text/javascript">
if (document.getElementById('btngreyscale').checked) {
alert('on');
} else {
(document.getElementById('btngreyscaleoff').checked) 
alert('off');
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You better keep two images - one colorful and one in greyscale. Once You converted the image from colorful to greyscale, You are not able to reconstruct the colors again! You voluntarily threw color information away! So You have to keep the original image to be able to switch back to it.

Comment: So how would I go about doing that? I have no idea, extremely new to JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

As Roman hocke already said, you are not able to use the greyscale to turn it back to a colorful image, since you threw some information away. To go back to a colorful image you just have to redraw the first image.

so in your code this would be:

```
(document.getElementById('btngreyscaleoff').checked) 
   alert('off');
   ctx.drawImage(image,0,0); 
}
```

This can be done that easily because you have already saved the image object in the DOM.